# html table is not set. alignment issues

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have an html table which is not set as I want. Following is the code for html table.

The text in the table td "Venue" and "Timing" has very far from their next td. I want them to close and center.

```
<table  style="
    border: 22px;
    background-color: darkcyan;
    margin: 22px;
    padding: 12px;"
><tr><td>
<h1>Welcome</h1><br>
Below is the registration form that is required to be filled out for joining the seminar. We have limited no. of 

seats. If you are interested, you may join us by submitting the required details. Please do not provide ambiguous 

information in the given form. Here are some information regarding the seminar are mentioned: <br><br>
</td></tr>

<tr><td><b>Starting Time: </b></td> <td>11:00 AM</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Venue: </b></td> <td>Pir Mehr Ali Shah Auditorium, Street # 1, H-8/1, Islamabad</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `<td colspan=2>` for second td.